# JPA Entity Inheritance and UniqueConstraint with DiscriminatorColumn

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Im using Hibernate with JPA 2.1 and I want to define an entity with two sub entities. My problem is that I want to define an UniqueConstraint with two columns: One MemberField and the DiscriminatorColumn.

**EDIT:** Because the answer of **Nicholas** solved my specific problem I changed the type of the parent class from abstract to non-abstract.

My code looks like this:

**Parent**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE")
@Table(name = "EXAMPLE", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "TYPE", "NAME" }) )
public class ExampleParent extends AbstractEntity
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 68642569598915089L;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 30)
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    ...

}
```

**Child 1**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("TYPE1")
public class Example1 extends ExampleParent
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7343475904198640674L;

    ...

}
```

**Child 2**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("TYPE2")
public class Example2 extends ExampleParent
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9077103283650704993L;

    ...

}
```

Now I don't want a UniqueConstraint on the name of the ExampleParent, because I want to be able to persist two objects of Example1 and Example2 with the same name. The following code should explain it:

```
@Autowired
Example1Repository example1Repo;

@Autowired
Example2Repository example2Repo;

Example1 example1 = new Example1();
example1.setName("example");
example1Repo.save(example1);

Example2 example2 = new Example2();
example2.setName("example");
example2Repo.save(example2);
```

So my goal is to set a UniqueConstraint of two columns but I actually want to use the DiscriminatorColumn and a field of my ExampleParent. The combination of the DiscriminatorColumn and the name should be unique.

My code doesn't work, so what are my options?

Comment: with your code above, you obtain a ConstraintViolationException ? You mean you cannont insert an Example1 and Example2 with the same Name ?

Comment: @oliv37 Yes I obtain a ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'example' for key ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an abstract base class I would expect that you would be using a `@MappedSuperclass` annotation instead of `@Inheritance`.

@MappedSuperclass is better for polymorphism, which is what you have. I don't think that @Inheritence supports polymorphism.

Comment: First of all I'm thankful for your answer. You are right: In my case it's better to use a `@MappedSuperclass`, because I won't have an own Entity of the parent class. Nevertheless I'm asking myself how to solve the originally problem. Is it possible to combine an `@UniqueConstraint` of a memberfield and the `@DiscriminatorColumn`?